# Displaying a html view from Model Gmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, gmaps4rails

Im working on a collaborative project.  Today I pulled down the updated files.  One of the guys started working on displaying coordinates on a map using gmaps4rails.  The weird part is he put the html in the model.  The problem is I cannot add in a database call for certain model.

here are the relationships:

Chef has many meals via chef_id

Chef has one location via chef_id

Both belong to chef

Location Model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_gmappable
belongs_to :chef
validates :chef_id, :zipcode, :address, presence: true

def gmaps4rails_address
  "#{address}, #{zipcode}"
end
      def gmaps4rails_infowindow
        "<h1>Chef: #{chef.name} </h1>" <<

        "<p>Address: #{address}, #{zipcode} </p>" <<

        "<h4>Meals: #{chef.meals.meal_name}</h4>"
  end

end
```

In other views I display chefs meals by:

```
<% chef.meals.limit(1).each do |meal| %>

    <li><%= meal.meal_name %></li>
    <li>$<%= meal.price %></li>

<% end %>
```

How exactly do I call chef.meals in the model and pass .limit to it.

Comment: Yeah, it was in the first versions of the gem, was not a good idea. You should really update gem to 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually even in maps4rails 1.x, you're not compelled to put htm in model.

Documentation is here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller

Do it this way:

```
@json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails do |user, marker|
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/users/my_template", :locals => { :object => user})
end
```

So you can use partials and pass them variables